# Access Update QueryDef Parameters not found

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I've two queries I'm trying to create with QueryDef.

This insert query works perfectly and I can assign the parameters:

```vb
Dim qryAddPackage As String: qryAddPackage = "" & _
    "INSERT INTO `RMF_tblPackages` " & _
    "(`SystemID`, `DoD`, `DateCreated`, `LastModified`, `LastUpdatedBy`) " & _
    "VALUES ([SystemID], [DoD], NOW(), NOW(), [UID])"

With CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, qryAddPackage)
    .Parameters!SystemID.Value = cbbSystems.Value
    .Parameters!DoD.Value = Me.txtDoD.Value
    .Parameters!UID.Value = strGetUserID()
    .Execute
End With
```

However, in this update query, I am only able to access the Parameter UID in the WHERE statement:

```vb
Dim qryUpdatePkg As String: qryUpdatePkg = "" & _
"UPDATE `RMF_tblPackages` " & _
"SET " & _
    "`SystemID` = [SystemID], `DoD` = [DoD], `LastModified` = NOW(), `LastUpdatedBy` = [UID] " & _
" WHERE `PackageID` = [PackageID]"

With CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, qryUpdatePkg)
    .Parameters("SystemID").Value = cbbSystems.Value
    .Parameters!DoD.Value = Me.txtDoD.Value
    .Parameters!UID.Value = strGetUserID()
    .Parameters!PackageID.Value = Me.lbxPackages.Value
    .Execute dbSeeChanges
End With
```

In every other line trying to assign a parameter, it just says that the parameter's name is not in the collection.

I've tried assigning them like this:

```vb
.Parameters("PackageID").Value = Me.lbxPackages.Value
```

As well, but that doesn't work either.

I tried just running the update query with some data and it worked fine so the query works.

`.Params.count` returns 1 as you would expect given it's only recognizing one param.

Any other ideas as to why the parameters aren't being recognized by that update query?

Comment: This SQL looks like MySQL syntax, not Access SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[ ]` for quoting identifiers. In Access the backtick is not valid (unlike MySQL). Also column names and parameter names use the same quoting characters, so you must choose different names for the parameters. Quoting identifiers is only necessary if the names collide with a reserved word or function name (like `Date`, `From`, `By`, `Order` etc).

```vb
Dim qryUpdatePkg As String

qryUpdatePkg = "UPDATE RMF_tblPackages " & _
"SET " & _
  "SystemID = prmSystemID, DoD = prmDoD, LastModified = Now(), LastUpdatedBy = prmUID " & _
" WHERE PackageID = prmPackageID"

With CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, qryUpdatePkg)
    .Parameters("prmSystemID").Value = cbbSystems.Value
    .Parameters!prmDoD.Value = Me.txtDoD.Value
    .Parameters!prmUID.Value = strGetUserID()
    .Parameters!prmPackageID.Value = Me.lbxPackages.Value
    .Execute dbSeeChanges
End With
```

Do the same changes in the first query.

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I corrected "escapes" to "quoted identifiers" terminology; "escapes" has more to do with e.g. doubling single-quote characters inside a string literal.